# paging through a list in google app engine and python

Tags: python, google-app-engine, pagination, jinja2

i have a list. (the list comes from a database query that is stored in memcache, ideally i will not query the database again.)

```
x = [thing1, thing2, thing3, ... thing100]
```

i'm using this function to generate the first 10 items in the list at a time.

```
def grouper(page_size, iterable):
        page = []
    for item in iterable:
        page.append(item)
        if len(page) == page_size:
            yield page
            page = []
    yield page
```

i'm calling the function

```
group = grouper(10, x)
```

i submit my result to my html like so

```
self.render("index.html", x-items = group.next())
```

in jinja2 i'm iterating through the group.next() and it correctly displays the first 10 items in the list.

my question is, what code do i put in my html('next' link) to get it it to run the function again, and display the next 10 items?

Answer (score 2):

When you query the database and you need paging, you use cursors. Both the datastore and NDB support cursors. So there is no need to save the query first in memcache.

But if you need to store it first in memcache, you can use your own cursor. See also this blog post from Nick Johnson: http://blog.notdot.net/2010/02/New-features-in-1-3-1-prerelease-Cursors

Comment: How do you create your own cursor while using memcache?

Comment: When you fetch the results of a query, you receive a list with the query results. The cursor is the position in the list, which can be saved in the session.